# Security difference between changing permissions versus using sudo to execute

Tags: linux, permissions, sudo, privilege-separation

If there is a program written by a normal user that requires root privileges (eg. a program that interacts with root processes) what is the difference between running this program using `sudo` vs. changing the program permissions with `chown root` and `chmod +s` from a security perspective?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### It hardly makes a difference, but with some caveats

Firstly, lets get two things out of the way first:

1. using `chown root` and `chmod +s` on a binary makes it a **SUID (Set User ID) binary**. I tell you this so it's easier to look up more information if you so please.
2. **sudo** itself is a **SUID binary**.

Because both methods allow a normal user to run the application as root, **if everything is set up correctly there is no difference whatsoever**.

But it's easier to mess up sudo privileges configurations than to mess up SUID binaries.

Some possible outcomes of misconfigurations or errors would be:

- The ability to sudo an application of the same name (if the path set in sudo permissions isn't abolute)
- If you move the application (and are using an absolute path) and you forget to change the sudo path, the user can no longer sudo the application.

  - Ever worse, if you the user can write to the old path it can now create a new binary with the old name and location and sudo it
  - The above also applies if you delete the binary

A small note about SUID binaries, some applications (like bash run without -p) drop the SUID bit when ran, thus dropping privileges back to those of the normal user.

Also, from time to time a sudo exploit is discovered. These usually require the user to be able to sudo *something* and therefor aren't usually if the user can't sudo anything at all. But frankly I would consider that a minor issue, but worth mentioning here nevertheless.

**I would just use a SUID**

Comment: A benefit of `sudo` is that for multiuser environments, it can be easily configured to only allow execution to some users. Well, not much harder for `SUID` actually, one just needs to have a separate group for and correct file permissions.